# How CAN devices should be connected

Tags: can

I am planning on connecting CAN devices from one single hub - where they are connected in parallel. Though on internet I found that most examples use 'device to device' connection. Is there a difference? The former seems a bit dangerous, because one damaged cable means other devices will be disconnected from each other.

Comment: "The former seems a bit dangerous, because one damaged cable means other devices will be disconnected from each other." Not necessarily less dangerous than keep on running as if nothing happened even when there is a node missing in the system. There's two ways to design safety-related systems when critical errors happen: either close everything down (industrial) or "limp home" the best you can in a safe mode (automotive/med-tech).

Answer (score 3):

CAN is a bus system with differential signals which are terminated at each end of the bus. Ideally you only have one physical line with no branching from one end of the bus to the other end. If that's not possible it's important to keep the branches short.
CAN is not made to be used in a tree structure (hub). It can work but it can also cause all kinds of problems.

If your connections are short and if your CAN speed is low you can get away with a lot of "not optimal" stuff. The longer the lines and the faster the transmission the more likely you'll run into problems if you don't have your design right.

You might want to read up on [Signal Reflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflections_of_signals_on_conducting_lines), and [impedance matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impedance_matching) to get an idea why the design of your network matters.

Answer (score 1):

I think you've got the normal and unusual situations the wrong way around for CAN bus.

The CAN bus is a multi-drop bus. Multiple devices are connected in parallel with each other, as [shown below](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAN_bus). The bus electrical spec' and bus protocol all are designed to cope with this and allow communication between this multitude of devices.

This means a CAN bus can be used to connect just two devices together.

The bus needs terminating resistors. The are at the ends of the bus, whatever implementation you have.

Like all multi-drop buses, it has the weakness that a broken connection will divide the bus and stop it operating as intended. It's possible the devices kept connected will still communicate but it depends on the bus wiring, design and any software operation.

However, the advantage is that it needs just two wires to connect a lot of devices together. In a car, it's target market, reducing wiring removes weight from the vehicle and a lot of wiring does add up.

Applications requiring better reliability than this Single Point Of Failure (SPOF) weakness can do things like run two buses, connecting each device to both buses, or segment the bus so a wiring short/open does not bring down the whole bus. But that depends on the system requirements and is assessed case by case.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem you may encounter by putting devices in parallel is due to the stubs each parallel device will create. This is due to the reflection created at your termination which could cancel the signal somewhere upstream.

For this reason, you want to make the star dispatch to each device short:
Meaning the length of theses connection is at maximum λ/10.

With λ the wavelength.

Comment: Some rule of thumb in CAN is to never have longer stubs than 0.3m.

Comment: Which according to the λ/10 rule would give a frequency of around 100 MHz isn't this far beyond the frequency we could expect the CAN bus to run on? This would mean they don't use the λ/10 rule of thumb in this case?